# std::ifstream doesn't work with -O3 optimization

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to run this code with optimization key -O3 (-O1 and O2 also do not work)

main.cpp:

```
#include "my_file.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    test_another();

    return 0;
}
```

my_file.hpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void test_another(){
    std::ifstream bar;
    bar.open("C:\\Users\\ische\\source\\repos\\OpenMpCpp\\test.in");
}
```

What I get: "Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault" in *istream* file when *basic_istream()* is called.

If function *test_another()* is moved to the *main.cpp* file - all works fine even with -O3 key. If program is compiled without any optimization key (O1, O2, O3) then it is a successful compilation.

I use Windows10, compiler is g++ from MinGW package: g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Anyone has any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Capital `O` ("oh") is what you want.

Comment: yes, lower-case "o" is the flag for output. The compiler is probably producing a file called "3"

Comment: Thanks, but I have a mistype here but not in my compilation command(

Comment: Is this truly your whole program and you are not using any other compilation flags or libraries that could interfere (like `-fsanitize=address` which makes some libraries nuts)? You compile with `g++ -O3 main.cpp` (and possibly `-o program_name`) and nothing else?

Comment: Ted Lygmo, yes, I am compiling only with -o and -O3 flags.

Comment: I have noticed some strange: placing test_another() in main.cpp today does not work. What I had done before this action: added bin directory of MinGw into Path variable, and restart my computer. But when I erased that path from Path test_another() in the main.cpp does not work.

Comment: I have tried to compile in Ubuntu with g++-7: all options work fine

Comment: Your problem with PATH makes me wonder if your compile is even working. If your build step fails the executable will not ever work.